# Rx Breaking Changes

Tags: system.reactive

I know that SL5 has a new property to count MouseClicks, but with help, I got this working when SL4 came out. Now I moved to a new machine, downloaded RX, and I understand the RX went through a few changes that has broken this code. I have tried, but I can't seem to navigate the transition away from FastSubject.

I would really like to fully understand the use of Subject here, and how to update the call to work with the current version of Rx.

```
public static IObservable<TSource> MonitorForDoubleClicks<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, TimeSpan doubleClickSpeed, IScheduler scheduler)
{
  return source.Multicast<TSource, TSource, TSource>(
      () => new FastSubject<TSource>(), 
      values =>
      {
        return values
            .TimeInterval(scheduler)  //injects a timestamp event arguments
            .Skip(1)                  // in order to determine an interval we need two of these, so this keeps the event in the collection, but does not process the first one in
            .Where(interval => interval.Interval <= doubleClickSpeed)     //second event has arrived, so we can test the interval
            .RemoveTimeInterval()                                         //take the time argument out of the event args
            .Take(1)                                                      //we take one of the events (the latest) and throw it
            .Repeat();                                                    //keep the observer alive forever
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

FastSubject is just Subject now, all subjects are fast :)  However, this is a weird way to check for double clicks.

How about just (warning: Coding via TextArea):

```
return source.Timestamp(scheduler)
    .Buffer(/*buffer of*/2, 1 /*advanced at a time*/)
    .Where(x => x[1].Timestamp - x[0].Timestamp < doubleClickSpeed)
    .Select(x => x[1]);
```